# Aesthethics do not work for individual geom_line's in R's ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to construct a plot with thin, transparent individual lines for individual people (indicated by the `id` column) and place a thick, solid average-across-people line on top of that.

My ggplot call looks like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = card_self, y = percent)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=id, color=id, size=1, alpha=0.8)) + 
  geom_line(data = data_averaged, aes(size=10, alpha=0.9)) +
  guides(color='none', alpha='none', size='none')
```

The result is this:
[image: R plot]

**The problem is** that changing the size/alpha aesthetics does not work as expected. I've tried setting them outside the `aes` argument and inside and the results are as random as it gets.

My full code to reproduce the plot is here:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("ggplot")
data <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                        3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
                                        4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
                                        5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                                        7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
                                        8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
                                        9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
                                        10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
                                        11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
                                        12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
                                        14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
                                        15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
                                        16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
                                        17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
                                        18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 
                                        19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
                                        20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
                                        21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
                                        22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
                                        23L, 23L, 23L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
                                        24L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
                                        25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
                                        27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 
                                        28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 
                                        29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
                                        30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L), .Label = c("P001", 
                                                                                                 "P002", "P003", "P004", "P005", "P006", "P007", "P008", "P009", 
                                                                                                 "P010", "P011", "P012", "P013", "P014", "P015", "P016", "P017", 
                                                                                                 "P018", "P019", "P020", "P021", "P022", "P023", "P024", "P025", 
                                                                                                 "P026", "P027", "P028", "P029", "P030"), class = "factor"), card_self = structure(c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     11L, 12L, 13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                     13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L), .Label = c("ace", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "ten", "jack", "queen", "king"), class = "factor"), percent = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.89, 1, 0.67, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.67, 0.22, 0.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.89, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 0, 1, 1, 0.89, 1, 1, 0.89, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.89, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.56, 0, 0.22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.56, 0.89, 0.67, 0.89, 0.67, 0.89, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.56, 0.67, 0.44, 0.89, 0.56, 0.56, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.44, 0.56, 0.11, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.22, 0.22, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.44, 0.33, 0.67, 0.33, 0.11, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0.89, 1, 0.89, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.78, 0.22, 0.56, 0.33, 0.22, 0.11, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.44, 0.11, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.78, 0.89, 0.56, 0.67, 0.67, 0.44, 0.44, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.44, 0.67, 0.22, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.78, 0.44, 0, 0.78, 0.44, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 0.22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.67, 0.44, 0.33, 0.56, 0.11, 0.33, 0.44, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.56, 0.44, 0.33, 0.22, 0.33, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.11, 0.11, 0.11, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.67, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.44, 0, 0.33, 0.22, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0.56, 0.67, 0.89, 0.89, 0.78, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.67, 0.44, 0.33, 0, 0.33, 0, 1, 1, 0.89, 0.78, 0.67, 0.44, 0.33, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 0.22, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.78, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.67, 0.44, 0.56, 0.22, 0.33, 0.44, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.56, 0.56, 0.22, 0.44, 0.44, 0.33, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.56, 0.11, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.44, 0.44, 0.33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.89, 0.67, 0.33, 0.33, 0.56, 0.22, 0.11, 0.11, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1, 1, 0.78, 0.22, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -360L), groups = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            id = structure(1:30, .Label = c("P001", "P002", "P003", "P004", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "P005", "P006", "P007", "P008", "P009", "P010", "P011", "P012", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "P013", "P014", "P015", "P016", "P017", "P018", "P019", "P020", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "P021", "P022", "P023", "P024", "P025", "P026", "P027", "P028", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "P029", "P030"), class = "factor"), .rows = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              1:12, 13:24, 25:36, 37:48, 49:60, 61:72, 73:84, 85:96, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              97:108, 109:120, 121:132, 133:144, 145:156, 157:168, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              169:180, 181:192, 193:204, 205:216, 217:228, 229:240, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              241:252, 253:264, 265:276, 277:288, 289:300, 301:312, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              313:324, 325:336, 337:348, 349:360), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
data_averaged <- data %>%
  group_by(card_self) %>%
  summarise(percent = mean(percent))


ggplot(data, aes(x = card_self, y = percent)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=id, color=id, size=1, alpha=0.8)) + 
  geom_line(data = data_averaged, aes(size=10, alpha=0.9)) +
  guides(color='none', alpha='none', size='none')
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the specific behaviour you are expecting versus what you are obtaining? Also, do individual plot (using just one of the `geom_line` statements) work as expected?

Comment: @AllDownhillFromHere A bit late now but I just reviewed this and had to point out that your comment is great. These are all questions that I should have thought of and explored before posting, but, alas, they did not occur to me. Very insightful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Important comment from teunbrand:

"In addition, I'd like to add that the reason the group aesthetic should be added is because discrete x-axes automatically group observations"

**Just add `group=1` to `ggplot()`**

The issue is that the second `geom_line` is not grouped. The data points must be grouped to connect correctly.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = card_self, y = percent, group=1)) +
    geom_line(aes(group=id, color=id, size=1, alpha=0.8)) + 
    geom_line(data = data_averaged, aes(size=10, alpha=0.9)) +
    guides(color='none', alpha='none', size='none')


# also works:
ggplot(data, aes(x = card_self, y = percent)) +
    geom_line(aes(group=id, color=id, size=1, alpha=0.8)) + 
    geom_line(data = data_averaged, aes(size=10, alpha=0.9, group=1)) +
    guides(color='none', alpha='none', size='none')
```

[image]

Comment: In addition, I'd like to add that the reason the group aesthetic should be added is because discrete x-axes automatically group observations.

Comment: Thank you very much for this important note. I will add it as an update and refer to your comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I guess the second geom line inherits the group/color aesthetics from the first one so I need to manually overwrite them? One problem persists with the aesthetics though: changing the alpha values makes no difference in the plot, e.g.
ggplot(data, aes(x = card_self, y = percent)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=id, color=id, alpha=0.7)) + 
  geom_line(data = data_averaged, aes(group=1, color='red', size=3, alpha=0.8)) +
  guides(color='none', alpha='none', size='none')

changing alpha values (while keeping the first one smaller) makes no difference to the plot --any ideas?

Comment: You could use `scale_alpha_manual(c(0.8, 0.9))`.